# Microsoft OneNote 2010 & symbolic links

Tags: symbolic-link, microsoft-onenote, mklink

OneNote uses a simple folder structure to organise its Sections and Sub-Sections - a Section is a file, a Sub-Section is a subfolder within the notebook which contains its own Section files.

What I'd like to do is create directory symbolic links within each Notebook that lead to another notebook - so a link to a folder elsewhere rather than within the notebook. I want to create a single master notebook that contains a collection of remote user notebooks - the users will run their notebooks as normal, the master notebook will be updated with all the subnotebooks.

I believe it *should* work, as creating subfolders manually or copying another notebook into the 'master' works. Whenever I've tried using `mklink /d` or `/j` to achieve this (both on local folders and remote servers) OneNote ignores them. Creating a local subfolder manually is picked up by OneNote within seconds.

My impression is that OneNote is using a deeper file system access than most applications. Has anyone else seen this or can comment?

Comment: Well, no suggestions or fixes from me or others. I've just tested this on a colleague's OneNote 2013 and it DOES work. Seems to be something with OneNote's coding that has changed, though I plan to try this on some VMs with different versions of OneNote.

Comment: OneNote 2003 also works with this process. Haven't yet tested 2007 but still can't get 2010 to work though. It just won't pick up the linked folders.

Comment: I've just come across this question. I'd have said it wouldn't work! Generally, only actions from within the Client have much impact and changes to the underlying files and folders are often ignored (apart from deletes of course). So a good find. I recommend that you add your own answer and then accept is as correct (I think you have to wait 24hr after adding your own answer).

Comment: I assume that you know that OneNote has a good internal linking mechanism too? You can create links to just about everything in OneNote very easily. Just open the shared notebooks and create links, paste them into the master. [Onetastic](http://www.omeratay.com/) has some macros to help.